# AS3 - Is it possible to access a sprite's child(s) from other parts of the code?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a sprite, attaching some graphics to it and a textfield. Then I am returning the sprite to another part of the code. At this point, is it possible to access the textfield through the parent sprite?

For example

```
private function foo():Sprite
{
  var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
  mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

  var tmpTextField:TextField = new TextField;
  tmpTextField.text = "SOME TEXT HERE";
  mySprite.addChild(tmpTextField); 

  return mySprite
}
```

Now I want to be able to manipulate the `tmpTextField` child of the `mySprite` parent, but through `mySprite` and not directly through `tmpTextField`.

I'm a beginner in AS3 so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Clarify what you are asking. Or perhaps state what exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: Another function loops over an array and calls `foo` for each element in the array. `foo` returns `mySprite` which has `tmpTextField` as child. I want that looping function to be able to manipulate `tmpTextField`, but I can't do that directly because I can't really store both `mySprite` and `tmpTextField` in separate variables and still have them associated to each other. Perhaps I can, but I don't know how.

Comment: In as3 Objects are passed by reference so you can store that reference in an array that is a class level memeber IE: private var myArra:Array = new Array(); then as long as you have the correct key or index to that array then you can access that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution to this problem is to use OOP. Make a class that extends `Sprite` and has your `TextField` as a property:

```
public class TextHolder extends Sprite
{

    private var _field:TextField;

    public function TextHolder()
    {
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

        _field = new TextField();
        addChild(_field);
    }

    public function get field():TextField{ return _field; }

}
```

Then update your code:

```
private function foo():TextHolder
{
    var mySprite:TextHolder = new TextHolder();
    mySprite.field.text = "SOME TEXT HERE";


    return mySprite;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the correct solution and I thought of that before, but since I haven't yet learned how to properly do OOP I was looking for other ways, but thanks for confirming that this is ultimately the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

If your Sprite has no other children, you can access the TextField like so:

```
    var spr: Sprite = foo();
    var txt: TextField = spr.getChildAt(0) as TextField;
```

Failing that, you can always name the TextField, so it is easier to find later. In your function, you add:

```
    ...
    tmpTextField.name = "myTF";
    ...
```

You can then reference it outside the function scope as follows:

```
    var txt: TextField = foo().getChildByName("myTF") as TextField;
```

Comment: Yeh, that's a clever way of doing it. I'll give that a try!